# HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized error for curl command

Tags: linux, curl, jasperserver

I'm trying to extract a report from Jasperserver using curl command, but getting error : HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized.

Following is the curl request and the response received from the app server.

REQUEST:

```
curl -u "superuser:superuser" -H "applicationId:123456" -H "location:SG" -G http://SERVER.com:8080/jasperserver-pro/rest_v2/reports/organizations/ORG1/Reports/REG/TEST_REPORT.csv --verbose
```

RESPONSE:

```
             
*   Trying SERVER_IP...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to SERVER.com (SERVER_IP) port 8080 (#0)
* Server auth using Basic with user 'superuser'
> GET /jasperserver-pro/rest_v2/reports/organizations/ORG1/Reports/REG/TEST_REPORT.csv HTTP/1.1
> Host: SERVER.com:8080
> Authorization: Basic KEYXXXXXXX==
> User-Agent: curl/7.61.1
> Accept: */*
> applicationId:123456
> 
< HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
< Expires: 0
< Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate
< X-Powered-By: Undertow/1
< Server: JBoss-EAP/7
< Pragma: no-cache
< Date: Fri, 21 Feb 2023 13:24:38 GMT
< Connection: keep-alive
< WWW-Authenticate: Negotiate
< Content-Type: text/html;charset=UTF-8
< Content-Length: 71
< 
* Connection #0 to host SERVER.com left intact
```

```
<html><head><title>Error</title></head><body>Unauthorized</body></html>
```

I have tried to login to server using the same credentials and execute the report, and it works fine; But I'm unable to do the same using curl.

I'm expecting to extract a csv report.

Comment: Well, maybe the server doesn't use basic auth ... Check how authorization looks like in a request that works

Answer (score 0):

Some servers may reject BASIC Authentication (i.e. refusing the use of simple username and password) to meet higher security requirments.

Per https://community.jaspersoft.com/documentation/jasperreports-server-authentication-cookbook/default-internal-authentication

jaspersever will redirect user to login page, you may have to figure out a way to deal with this (e.g. by using Selenium).